# foreach ($_POST)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I'm using a multiple checkboxs in a form and query the database with no problems. Now I want to add a dropdown list and combine it with the query with the checkboxs. When I run this I get a

```
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Here is my form

```
     <form name="search_form" method="post" action="event_list">
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td>Venue</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="AAC"><label >AAC</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="AKC" id="check_list[]"/><label >AKC</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="ASCA"/><label >ASCA</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="CKE"/><label >CKE</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="CPE"/><label >CPE</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="DOCNA"/><label >DOCNA</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="NADAC"><label >NADAC</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="TDAA"/><label >TDAA</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="UKC"/><label >UKC</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="UKI"/><label >UKI</label><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" action="" value="USDAA"/><label >USDAA</label><br />
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td style="text-align: left;">State:</td>
     <td style="text-align: left;">
     <select name="state" id="state" onChange="setCities();">
     <option name="drop_down[]" value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
     <option name="drop_down[]" value="Texas">Texas</option>
     </select>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </form>
```

Here is my PHP

```
     <?php 
     $options = Array();
     $options2 = Array();
     foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $check)
     $options[] = 'venue=' . "'$check'"; 

     foreach ($_POST['drop_down'] as $drop)
     $options2[] = 'state=' . "'$drop'";

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM venue_event_all";
     if (count($options))
     $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $options);
     if (count($options2))
     $sql .= " AND " . implode(' OR ', $options2);

    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `<select>` input, the value of `<option>` is sent paired with the name of the select to POST/GET.

Setting a `name` on the `option` itself will not do anything. The dropdown value will still go with the name of the select.

You can check it by using this

```
echo $_POST['state'];
```

So, use this value to set into your query.

Edit : Obligatory - Please don't use MySQL as it is deprecated and not maintained by PHP any more. Use MySQLi, or PDO. Also, please sanitize your inputs before using them in the query. [This is what happens when you don't.](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I was over thinking and used this and works great. thanks for your help.<?php 
$options = Array();
$state = $_POST['state'];
foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $check)
   $options[] = 'venue=' . "'$check'"; // don't forget to escape $i somehow!

$sql = "SELECT * FROM venue_event_all";
if (count($options))
   $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $options);
   $sql .= " AND state=" . "'$state'" ;

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

Answer (score 0):

foreach will show you error, if array is empty or is not set, so you need to check it first:

```
if(isset($_POST[0]) and count($_POST) > 0)
{
 foreach...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't just rant about sql injection but give you a solution.
The only way to have your query **safe** with sensible amount of code is [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) library
(Based on Jeffrey code, not tested, but use in production freely):

```
<?php 
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new SafeMysql();
$options = array();

if (!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $options[] = $db->parse('venue IN (?a)', $_POST['check_list']);
}
if (!empty($_POST['drop_down'])) {
    $options[] = $db->parse('state IN (?a)', $_POST['drop_down']);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM venue_event_all";
if ($options) {
    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $options);
}
$data = $db->getAll($sql);
```